# Public Sharepoint 2010 testbed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am on a contract working as a PM at a company that uses Sharepoint 2010. They are not exploiting it very well (nor are there plans to upgrade to 2013--see previous statement). It would be helpful to me, and possibly a good thing to do overall, if I could set up a useful Sharepoint 2010 example (following, for instance, suggestions in Dux Raymond Sy's "SharePoint 2010 for Project Management), but that book's sample hosting is gone.

Is there some place that for minimal cost (or none) I could do such a demo? Internally, there is no current likelihood I will get admin privs to do so.

Comment: They have a tool locked away from the users? This probably isn't your best battle to choose to fight as a contract employee.

Comment: Yes, and that is on my mind ;-). But 2010 is good enough (if not as good as 2013 by any stretch of the imagination) that there could be some leverage if I can work without the internal battle over admin rights.

Comment: do you want a place where you can build sharepoint farm and give them the demo, am i right?

Comment: Yup. A place where I can configure/build a Sharepoint 2010 site and demo the results. Thanks.

Comment: There are a few third party companies that will rent you a server. http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-foundation-2010/ is one I have used on a small scale and not had any problems with.

Comment: Thanks. Their minimum looks like too much server for too much money just to explore. There is a local Sharepoint meetup next week--I think I'll see if someone there has an idea (although finding a few people at a Sharepoint meetup still on 2010 may be fun). 

At some point, this becomes too much trouble, too. What could be an interesting side project sucks too much effort out of just getting the extant job done ;-).